# What is the second pickup/interact option for this grenade?

Tags: borderlands-3

I played the Eridian slot machine in Sanctuary and it gave me this grenade:

[image: Grenade image]

I haven't noticed until today the second pickup option that is also mapped to the <kbd>E</kbd> key.  It's description says "~4.3s" which I understood as "around 4.3 seconds" but why is it there? I also played the regular cash machine and the gun I got from it also had this option.  Nothing in the game controls seems say anything about this.  What does it mean?

Comment: I'd guess that the first option is to pick it up into your inventory and the second option is to swap it with your currently equipped grenade. Borderlands 2 had that as well if I remember correctly. Just as well as multiple other games

Comment: What is the other grenade you are currently wearing? Is there a lock in Borderlands 3 when swapping gear (I recall in Borderlands 2 there we glitches related to weapon swaps, maybe devs prevent it from start and 4.3s preventing you from having advantage over poor enemies)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second option is the same for guns as it is for grenades. Holding the pickup button will instead equip the item and replace it with the one you currently have equipped.

The equipped one will be placed in your inventory. If your inventory is full you will drop the currently equipped item.

This is what it is supposed to look like. It should say 'Take' and 'Equip'.
[image]

I still believe this ~4.3s to be a bug.

Comment: But what is "~4.3s" ? I don't remember this text.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that is. My guess is that it was bugged out momentarily. I imagine on any other grenade it would display the proper 'equip' text. I've never seen anything other than equip in any borderlands game including 3

Comment: I'm going to say it was a bug that has either been patched, or was a one off thing - it no longer says ~4.3s for me anymore.

Comment: There is a semi-frequent bug where button prompts get replaced with seemingly random text, which you encountered here. Something similar can happen with the names and levels on enemy health bars. It's not patched yet.